# My if statement which worked before no longer works

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I am trying to create an if else statement that checks multiple values, one after another, to see whether they are null or not.

The if else statement that I created worked perfectly earlier, but after restarting my pc it no longer works.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    //Declare Strings
    String ProjectNo, Location, VP;

    //Store values from text boxes into strings
    ProjectNo = txtProjectNum.getText();
    Location = txtLocation.getText();
    VP = txtVPNo.getText();


    if(ProjectNo == null){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No fields can be left empty!");

    }

    else if (Location == null){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No fields can be left empty!");

    }

    else if (VP == null){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No fields can be left empty!");

    }

    else{

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All fields have been filled in!");

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you were always checking for nulls and not empty Strings ("")?

Comment: Yes I have always checked for null as opposed to using ""@Riaan Nel

Comment: Not related to your issue, but your string variables should start with a lower-case letter. Otherwise, they look like classes.

Comment: What type are `txtProject` and such? I mean, if they're `JTextComponent` subclass instances, I don't think [`getText`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) ever returns `null`. (Same for AWT's [`TextComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/TextComponent.html#getText()) subclasses.)

Comment: Thank you, I will be sure to change my naming conventions in future @sleepToken

Comment: They are JTextFields @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Probably best to to replace `== null` with `.equals("")` or `.isEmpty()`

Comment: I will try that now @sleepToken

Comment: That seems to have worked for me @sleepToken What reason could there be for it working one minute and not working the next?

Comment: Tristan there's a chance that you hadn't initialize one of your JTextComponents. So, the fields themselves were null, causing the null fields.getText() to also return null. Once the fields exist however, I agree with @T.J.Crowder that they should return the empty string as their content.

Comment: Maybe previous time you weren't running version of code you are showing to us but some even earlier compiled version which correctly checked `.isEmpty()` instead of `== null` (later you could edit `.java` source text but not compile it to `.class` file). It is hard to tell but code you posted simply couldn't work the way you wanted, unless `txtProjectNum` or `txtLocation` aren't `JTextFields`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I was truly stumped on that one. And thank you @sleepToken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the [`getText` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText()) never returns `null`. If you want to check for an empty field, check `.length() == 0` or [`.isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()). You might consider [`.trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()) first. E.g.:

```
if (projectNo.trim().isEmpty()) {
```

Or perhaps `trim` when getting the text into the variable:

```
projectNo = txtProjectNum.getText().trim();
// ...
if (projectNo.isEmpty()) {
```

Comment: Or use https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()

Comment: @JoachimRohde - Good point, if you don't want it trimmed when you use it but you do want to consider it blank if it's just whitespace...